# New tag request: "wonderworkshop"

Tags: feature-request, tags

My company ([Wonder Workshop](https://www.makewonder.com/)) would like to direct hobbyists, students, and educators to discuss the more technical aspects of our robots here at robotics.stackexchange.com .  And specifically we'd like to encourage them to use the tag "wonderworkshop" to improve the signal in the discussion.
Unfortunately nobody at the company has sufficient reputation to create new tags, so I come begging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once there are on-topic questions that introduce the immediate need for a new tag, it can be created. If there are no questions yet, then the tag cannot be created. At the moment, I don't see any questions regarding your company (it is possible I missed) and so we can't create that tag yet.

I recommend giving [this post a read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/395044) from meta for more information.

Also, a tag named after a company in R.SE sounds like an off-topic tag. When questions regarding your products start coming in, it may be more appropriate to have tags about the products themselves. An example of this would be CleverBots

Answer (score 5):

This situation is similar to what we did with the iRobot Create.  (We direct users with questions to this site).  Although when Robotics.StackExchange started the Create was already a fairly established hobby robot.

I would suggest that you have a group of robotics engineers at your company start participating on this site.  (Ask questions, answer questions, make edits, etc.)  And not just on questions related to your products.  Your increased reputation can only help, and it will help make you not a spammer.

Answer (score 4):

As [koverman47 suggests](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1364/37) for a tag to exist we need a question which is [on topic for Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on the site to require that tag. As [koverman47](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20709/koverman47) says, product tags such as [cleverbots](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleverbots) would be acceptable, however meta tags such as [wonderworkshop](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonderworkshop) would not.

Having said that, you are more than welcome to suggest your customers ask questions about your products here, and anyone with [the create-tags privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) should be able to create one when suggesting an edit to an existing question which requires it, and you currently only need 5 upvotes to be that person. Even if someone doesn't have [create-tags privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) they can always flag a question and explain why they think it is incorrectly tagged.

Also, when the tags are created, we would appreciate it if you could review any tag wikis for your own products, to ensure they are correct, submitting suggested tag wiki updates if necessary.

Finally, while we are happy to have questions about your products here, please read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How not to be a spammer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). This should help you avoid having your questions and answers being flagged as spam.

Comment: thanks @koverman47 and Mark Booth for the helpful replies and the "read this" links. it's appreciated.
the as-needed approach to tag creation makes sense, and from the various readme links, I think our vision of how people would use the community in relation to our robots lines up quite well.  ie, we're already directing bug reports to other channels, ditto feature-requests etc.   'cleverbots' versus 'wonderworkshop' also makes sense. I think we'll direct folks here for appropriate questions, and ask them to include 'cleverbots' as a word in the subject and body.